# How to enable HTTPS stream wrappers

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I installed php5 on my windows system and tried to execute the following script with a command-line console:

```
<?php
// load in credentials
$creds = parse_ini_file('/etc/aws.conf');

// Define query string keys/values
$params = array(
    'Action' => 'DescribeAvailabilityZones',
    'AWSAccessKeyId' => $creds['access_key'],
    'Timestamp' => gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'),
    'Version' => '2008-05-05',
    'ZoneName.0' => 'us-east-1a',
    'ZoneName.1' => 'us-east-1b',
    'ZoneName.2' => 'us-east-1c',
    'SignatureVersion' => 2,
    'SignatureMethod' => 'HmacSHA256'
);

uksort($params, 'strnatcmp');
$qstr = '';
foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
    $qstr .= "&{$key}=".rawurlencode($val);
}
$qstr = substr($qstr, 1);

// Signature Version 2
$str = "GET\n"
     . "ec2.amazonaws.com\n"
     . "/\n"
     . $qstr;

// Generate base64-encoded RFC 2104-compliant HMAC-SHA256
// signature with Secret Key using PHP 5's native 
// hash_hmac function.
$params['Signature'] = base64_encode(
    hash_hmac('sha256', $str, $creds['secret_key'], true)
);

// simple GET request to EC2 Query API with regular URL 
// encoded query string
$req = 'https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?' . http_build_query(
    $params
);
$result = file_get_contents($req);

// do something with the XML response
echo $result;
```

But it says that it's unable to find the wrapper "https" and asks if I forget to enable it when I configured PHP.

What is the problem and how to settle it?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to enable https when you configured PHP?

Answer (score 45):

1: Check which wrappers are installed.

```
<?php var_dump(stream_get_wrappers()); ?>
```

2: If you dont see "https" on the list, add to/uncomment from php.ini

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Restart your server*, and your done.

*if server fails to restart go download php_openssl.dll from someplace and stick it in your extensions directory defined in the php.ini file, restart server, say a few hell mary's and pray.

Comment: btw: i detest curl, stick with the fopen's like file_get_contents.... fsockopen is like the daddy.

Comment: Regarding @Costa comment, beware often the Command Line php is picking up a different php.ini file, that's caught me out before.

Comment: Yup, that's why I mentioned it. :) If you need to check what streams are available to the command line, that's the command to use (I was in the situation you describe).

Comment: dont forget to uncomment `extension_dir ` in `php.ini'

Comment: I found it as `;extension=openssl`  (remove the semicolon to uncomment it.)

Comment: What if we **do** see "https" on the list and it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 10):

The `file_get_contents` line, at the end of your script, is trying to send an HTTPS request -- see the URL in `$req`, which starts by `'https://ec2...'`.

For this to be possible, PHP needs a "wrapper" to send HTTPS requests -- which doesn't seem to be installed on your system ; which means you cannot send HTTPS requests using the `fopen` familly of functions.

For more informations about stream wrappers, if you are curious, you can take a look at [List of Supported Protocols/Wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php), and, in your case, [HTTP and HTTPS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php).

You'll either have to install the HTTPs wrapper -- on Windows, I have no idea how to do that, unfortunately...

Or you'll have to use something else that `file_get_contents` to send your HTTPS request -- I would use the functions provided by the [curl](http://www.php.net/curl) extension *(Here, too, not sure it will work "out of the box", though :-( )*.

For an example, you can take a look at what's proposed on the manual page of [`curl_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) :

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Note you'll probably have to set a couple more options, using [`curl_setopt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) -- you should go through that page : there are a lot of useful options ;-)

As a sidenote, you are using this line at the beginning of your script :

```
$creds = parse_ini_file('/etc/aws.conf');
```

The path `/etc/aws.conf` feels strange, as you said you are using a Windows system : this looks like the kind of path one would use on an UNIX/Linux system.

Comment: I believe he needs to install SSL support to get that on Windows

Answer (score 4):

Open `php.ini`. Find this line:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; ...
;extension=ext/php_oci8.dll
extension=ext/php_openssl.dll         ; <---- you want this
;extension=ext/php_pdo_firebird.dll
; ...
```

you want to uncomment the `extension=ext/php_openssl.dll` line. Make sure there is a `pho_openssl.dll` file in the `ext/` directory, relative to your `php.ini` (or maybe more importantly to the `extension_dir` variable in the ini).

Answer (score 2):

Simple. I had this error and gave me such headaches. Enable (uncomment the line `extension=php_openssl.dll`) in your php.ini file. This will solve the issue.