# Get contents of an XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, url, curl, file-get-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [file_get_contents with https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https)
>   [Problems getting XML content via https using SimpleXML and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883575/problems-getting-xml-content-via-https-using-simplexml-and-php)

I have the URL:

> 

Which loads a file like this one:

```
<calendars>
    <calendar accommodation_id="1234567">
        <day date="2012-08-09" vacancy="false" minimum_nights="7" arrival_day="true"/>
        <day date="2012-08-10" vacancy="false" minimum_nights="3" arrival_day="true"/>
        <day date="2012-08-11" vacancy="false" minimum_nights="3" arrival_day="true"/>
        ...
        <day date="2014-01-31" vacancy="true" minimum_nights="3" arrival_day="true"/>
    </calendar>
</calendars>
```

For some reason my script won't let me get the contents of this file. I'm using the same script as i have been with other URLs but this will always fail.

My script is:

```
$accom2 = file_get_contents();

print_r($accom2);
```

Is there something I need to do for this type of URL?

Comment: According to [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php#refsect1-wrappers.http-notes), you need openssl enabled. Do you have it enabled? (And please don't repeat a question, move back to your older one)

Comment: Please do not duplicate questions. Instead, edit your previous one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

probably an answer here: (if protocol is the issue)

[How to get file_get_contents() to work with HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/file-get-contents-with-https)

Comment: Yes it was the extension=php_openssl.dll that needed to be activated in my php.ini thanks!!

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer. Just saying, it's not your fault that OP is rather unspecific.

Comment: Duplicates should not be posted as answer. You have comments and flags for that.

Comment: i wasn't aware of it... I can't delete and make only a comment as it's an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php), I tested it's working for me

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://www.casapilot.com/api/1/accommodations/calendar.xml?auth_token=hyXHjP8QdrRuX8q3FsbC&id[]=1049165');

print_r($xml);
?>
```

Comment: But presumably `file_get_contents()` would also work for you?