# Error when loading external xml file with php via https : SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE

Tags: php, xml

I can't get a xml file to load.

This code works great:

```
$url = 'http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
```

But this one

```
$url = 'https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=105551';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
```

doesn't work. I get this error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /storage/content/59/113059/boardgamelevelup.com/public_html/index.php on line 19 Warning: simplexml_load_file(): Failed to enable crypto in /storage/content/59/113059/boardgamelevelup.com/public_html/index.php on line 19 Warning: simplexml_load_file(https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=105551): failed to open stream: operation failed in /storage/content/59/113059/boardgamelevelup.com/public_html/index.php on line 19 Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=105551" in /storage/content/59/113059/boardgamelevelup.com/public_html/index.php on line 19

The xml file from boardgamegeek works on other sites. Should I use a different php code to load that xml file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get contents of an XML file using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885169/get-contents-of-an-xml-file-using-php)

Comment: You've got a SSL problem to address with your web servers configuration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

short cookbook answer:

1. Download https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt and place that file on your server.
2. Add

   ```
   $context = stream_context_create(array('ssl'=>array(
       'verify_peer' => true,
       'cafile' => '/path/to/ca-bundle.crt'
   )));
   libxml_set_streams_context($context);
   ```

to your script so it gets executed before simplexml_load_file().
Or - instead of the code above - set `openssl.cafile=/path/to/ca-bundle.crt` in your php.ini.

Very short explaination:
Your php version uses openssl to handle the http**s** transport. openssl tries to verify whether the server really is who it claims to be. It does that by checking whether its certificate is trusted. A X.509 certificate contains some data about the owner and is signed by an issuer (itself having a certificate that is again signed and so on and on until a certificate where owner and issuer are identical -> self-signed/root certificate). A certificate is considered "trusted" if in that chain of certificates there is (at least) one certificate on which openssl "says": "ok, I have been *instructed* to trust this one". This instruction takes the form of (or *can* take the form of) "here's a file containing certificates that you're supposed to trust" (cafile).
The above code tells the libxml-wrapper of php to tell openssl where that cafile is when simplexml_load_file uses the https/openssl-wrapper.
And `openssl.cafile=/path/to/ca-bundle.crt` just sets it as default; unless instructed otherwise all openssl operations will use that file - including libxml/simple_xml_loadfile.

The ca-bundle.crt I've linked to is from a project that "claims" to provide the extracted root certificates as shipped with mozilla firefox. Regarding "claims": I have no reason to doubt that this really is the untampered root cert list; but you never know: You're putting your trust a) in this project and b) mozilla doing a good job and only putting trustworthy certificates in that list....

for more explaination see http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Transport-Layer-Security-%28HTTPS-SSL-and-TLS%29.html#php-streams

Comment: Thank you very much VolkerK! That worked. Also thank you for the explanation, that helped to understand the problem.

Comment: couple of addition for googlers like me: `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'` to find php.ini
`wget -P /path/to/cert/ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt` to save cert to the folder. then restart apache `systemctl restart httpd`

Answer (score 9):

The work and example that @VolkerK displayed was excellent and simple.
While this method didn't work for me, I took it one step further and basically removed the security for the moment.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('ssl'=>array(
    'verify_peer' => false, 
    "verify_peer_name"=>false
    )));

libxml_set_streams_context($context);

$sxml = simplexml_load_file($webhostedXMLfile);
```

Yes, this is bad practice, but sometimes you need a temp fix instead of messages like this:

> Warning: simplexml_load_file(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in
>   /srv/www/resources/public_html/files/etc/file.php on line 150 Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(): Failed to enable crypto in
>   /srv/www/resources/public_html/files/etc/file.php on line 150

I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It saved me definetely

Comment: Just using 'verify_peer'  set to false was enough in my case.