# Fopen accept self signed certificate

Tags: php, fopen, php-5.6, nuxeo

i would like to get the result of my page in https in a php variable but the fopen fonction return false;

i think this error can be product by the ssl certifacte which is self signed

```
fopen("https://192.168.1.1:8443", "rb"))
```

> Warning: fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Is it a php ssl configuration to accept all certificate ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

see [Error when loading external xml file with php via https : SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621929/error-when-loading-external-xml-file-with-php-via-https-ssl3-get-server-certif/32622437#32622437)

Export your self-signed certificate PEM-encoded and append it to ca-bundle.crt (or if there is no ca-bundle.crt yet, just rename your export file)

Then use

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('ssl'=>array(
    'verify_peer' => true,
    'cafile' => '/path/to/ca-bundle.crt'
)));
$fd = fopen("https://192.168.1.1:8443", "rb", false, $context);
```

see [SSL context options](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php) and [stream_context_create](http://docs.php.net/stream_context_create)

Answer (score 20):

Check this - http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

```
<?php
$opts=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  

$response = fopen("https://192.168.1.1:8443", 'rb', false, stream_context_create($opts));

echo $response; ?>
```

Comment: It should be `$response = fopen("https://192.168.1.1:8443", 'rb', false, stream_context_create($opts));` You skipped 1 parameter