# Cannot load a specific URL with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, curl

I am scraping http://www.beautyinzone.net/.

I am using simple `file_get_contents()` to load this URL.

Its working perfectly on my localhost. But it does not work when I upload on my live server.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.beautyinzone.net/): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in script.php on line 36 page
```

If I open some other URL it works fine.

URL

I have tried with cURL as well but that shows empty page, returns nothing.

One thought came in my mind that maybe I am blocked, but it should not be like that that said website using my servers.

What possible issue can be preventing me loading that URL?

Comment: file_get_contents works for me

Comment: [cURL works for me](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/xVd7o)

Comment: Yeah it does on localhost as well ... but see .. I placed scraper here on my server ... it does not scrape http://www.coszi.com/crawl/beautyinzone.php

Comment: I can't think of any other reason than the server being blocked.

Comment: @Barmar I cant think too ... its kind of weird situation ...

Comment: Have you tried `stream_get_contents()` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834038/php-find-and-get-value-based-on-another-one-from-html-table-parsed-file/34835046#34835046

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me. 
Try to get the error by below code

```
if (!$content = file_get_contents("http://www.beautyinzone.net/")) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo $error['message'];
} else {
    echo "working fine";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the remote server is delaying to reply you've re received a http timeout error. it's just normal.

TCP sockets has timeout set and when this timeout is reached a timeout error is raised. Generally the timeout is 30 seconds (By default the **default_socket_timeout** `php.ini` setting is used).

Maybe you want set (increase) a custom timeout yourself:

```
<?php

$http_context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 60.0 # 60 seconds
    )
));
$url = 'http://www.beautyinzone.net';
$content = file_get_contents($url, false, $http_context);
```

Via cURL just use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
```

Comment: tried it too ... getting same error ... and getting nothing returned from cURL

Comment: Well, have you been tested with other URLs?

Comment: Yes, I have tested with some other URLs and those are loading fine

Comment: it looks like I am banned from there ... even I have never scraped that site using my servers :(

Comment: hmm how about set a `User-agent` header?

Comment: I have done everything man :P I am scraping with user-agents with file_get_contents and cURL as welll ... but it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this cURL snippet

```
function retrieve_curl_info() {
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
         CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.beautyinzone.net/',
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
     ));
     $output = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     return $output
}
```

Also, check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294124/php-file-get-contents-not-working)