# Why this is printing 0?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to do a Instagram Follower count in PHP. (as JavaScript isn't working)

I got this PHP script but it's not working.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/';
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$count = 0;
if(preg_match('#followed_by": {"count": (.*?)}#', $str, $match)) {
     $count = $match[1];
} echo $count;
?>
```

Comment: I assume because your preg_match statement returns false and so count it never updated.

Comment: You should check the content of `$str`, as https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen might be disabled

Comment: Also, that string probably doesn't exist in the HTML that you are downloading. Instead, it exists in the DOM which is generated by JavaScript.

Comment: I think that `$str` is an HTML, but I don't know lot about of PHP.

Comment: **Off-topic: Cannot Reproduce** / **Needs Debugging Details** https://3v4l.org/Jtu8K  If this is not about the `preg_match()` call, but about scraping the url, then remove everything after the `file_get_contents()` line in your question.  Anything helpful to you in https://stackoverflow.com/q/35234096/2943403 ?

Comment: i don't understand...? i want it to get the followers of an Instagram account, getting the HTML of the ig account || or using the url/?__a=1 will print a JSON

Comment: Why are you doing this using a regexp instead of parsing the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Your Kind Information ->>**

**1.** Instagram Has Changed `#followed_by` To `#edge_followed_by` (source: [view-source:https://www.instagram.com/cristiano](http://view-source:https://www.instagram.com/cristiano)), This Is One Of The Reasons Why It Is Returning 0.

**2.** Add "?__a=1" To Insta Profile Url **(https://www.instagram.com/cristiano/?__a=1)** And You Will Get Json, Just Decode Json And Get The Value.

**3.** These Are Not Legal Ways To Get Information From Instagram. I Prefer To Use [Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/), Which Is Easy To Use And Free.

**UPDATE**

**4.** Or You Can Get Followers From `<meta>` Tags Instead Of `<script>` Tags (*Example* - `<meta content="310m Followers, 476 Following, 3,095 Posts - See Instagram photos and videos from Cristiano Ronaldo (@cristiano)" name="description" />` )

Comment: Thanks! Im doing Instagram API.

Comment: Yup, that would be right.