# Error file_get_contents in Laravel in Jobs

Tags: laravel, php-7

When work the jobs say:

> ErrorException: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/mmicube/public_html/app/Jobs/ProcesarPeliculas.php:33 Stack trace:
>       0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_get_conten...', '/home/mmicube/p...', 33, Array)
>       1 /home/mmicube/public_html/app/Jobs/ProcesarPeliculas.php(33): file_get_contents('https://api.the...')
>       and more...

But if I try in a page (out of jobs) the `file_get_contents()` is fine. Why?

I configured the PHP ea-php70:

```
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = On
display_errors = Off
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 32M
post_max_size = 8M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php72"
upload_max_filesize = 2M
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

I try with http and https and nothing... don't work.

I using Centos7.5 with cPanel, ea-php70.

`phpinfo()`:

[image]

Comment: Please do a `phpinfo()` from inside a laravel view to see the actual config. Maybe the config used by that vhost is not the same as the one you opened. 
This is likely no laravel issue but simply a configuration issue.

Comment: Different php.ini for web and cli ... try `php -r 'echo ini_get("allow_url_fopen");'

Comment: @TimSch the image phpinfo() is in the post, thanks

Comment: Okay.. that's really strange. It's not really a solution but some workaround. Try to use cURL instead like mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294124/php-file-get-contents-not-working

Comment: Please try @simonecosci command. It took a while to get what he meant but he's absolutely correct.

Comment: This command is put in console? (i can access ssh) @TimSch

Comment: correct. This should return false.

Comment: @TimSch i try with this command and nothing, say: "".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184275/discussion-between-timsch-and-abraham-morales).