# using Simple Dom parser to Get content of wiki infobox

Tags: php

I try to display the content of Wikipedia infobox using simple Dom Parser but it gives me problem. this is the code.`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//The folder where you uploaded simple_html_dom.php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

//Wikipedia page to parse
$html = file_get_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burger_King');

foreach ( $html->find ( 'table[class=infobox vcard]' ) as $element ) {

    $cells = $element->find('td');

    $i = 0;

    foreach($cells as $cell) {


        $left[$i] = $cell->plaintext;

        if (!(empty($left[$i]))) {

            $i = $i + 1;

        }

    }


    $cells = $element->find('th');

    $i = 0;

    foreach($cells as $cell) {

        $right[$i] = $cell->plaintext;

        if (!(empty($right[$i]))) {

            $i = $i + 1;

        }

    }


print_r ($right);

echo "<br><br><br>";

print_r ($left);

//If you want to know what kind of industry burger king is
//echo "Burger king is $right[2], $left[2]

}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

The code is not working on any other pages like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom, it works ony using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burger_King.
this is the error message I am getting Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\MyApps\Inbox.php on line 16

Comment: `simple_html_dom.php` is it available in your php file?

Comment: yes is in my Local folder

Comment: HTTPS wrapper enabled?

Comment: No! but I have now found how to enable it by using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305954/how-to-enable-https-stream-wrappers.

Comment: Thanks. It works but with only https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burger_King. Do know why it is not working with other pages like   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India

Answer (score 1):

**1:** This code doesn't work for you because you are trying to fetch the table with class="infobox vcard", which is for companies, on a country page which is class="infobox geography vcard".

**2:** That thus isn't the only problem because you are running out of memory for sure.

Substitute

```
$html = file_get_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom');
```

with:

```
$url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($curl_scraped_page, true, false);
```

And you should get something like

```
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated XXX) (tried to allocate 40 bytes) 
in /simple_html_dom.php on line 1544
```

**3:** If you will be able to fix the previous problems you will also have to update your code, which probably won't work

#### Edit 1:

My favourite way to avoid this problem is to use google cache, which has a "only text" version.
This usually avoids the need to store a huge amount of data, which is one of the things not making your code work. The major downside owever is that Google cache doesn't know that to do with `th`so what was inside just disapperars.

I'll look for an alternative, meanwhile here's the code XD

```
<?php

require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
//$html = file_get_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom');

    //q = website to fetch, leave "cache:"
    $url = 'http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?strip=1&q=cache:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load($curl_scraped_page, true, false);


//echo $html;


foreach ( $html->find ( 'table[class=infobox geography vcard]' ) as $element ) {


    $cells = $element->find('td');

    $i = 0;

    foreach($cells as $cell) {


        $left[$i] = $cell->plaintext;

        if (!(empty($left[$i]))) {

            $i = $i + 1;

        }

    }


print_r ($left);

}


?>
```

If I helped you (and I'm sure I did), mark as best answer and thumbs up :P

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the error comes from table[class=infobox vcard], this only retrieved content of table which class =Infobox