# Uncaught Error: Class 'WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder' not found- MS Azure | PHP

Tags: php, azure, connection-string, azure-table-storage

I have created the composer.json file in my root folder where my index.php file is presents, with the following code in it:

```
{
 "require": {
    "microsoft/windowsazure": "^0.5"
 }
}
```

and on downloading composer.phar, I have installed it using:

```
php composer.phar install
```

I'm trying to create a table and add entities to it in php. I use the command

```
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=******;AccountKey=***/***************************/******************/**********************************==';
$tableRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createTableService($connectionString);
try {
  // Create table.
  $tableRestProxy->createTable("mytable");
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
  $code = $e->getCode();
  $error_message = $e->getMessage();
  echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}
```

When I run this on local host on my Ubuntu, I get an error saying-

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder' not found in /home/my_folder/php-docs-hello-world-master/index.php:30
```

If I add

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

before defining my $connectionString, then my error changes to:

```
/index.php - Uncaught RuntimeException: Error creating resource: [message] fopen(https://eyesav.table.core.windows.net/Tables): failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport &quot;http&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

Can someone help me figure out this issue, if it is with the installation of my composer, or my connectionString, or something else?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone help me figure out this issue, if it is with the installation of my composer, or my connectionString, or something else?

If I use the code you mentioned, I also could reproduce the issue you mentioned.

Please have a try to use following code to create the table client. It works for me.

```
 use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Table\TableRestProxy;
 use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;
 $tableClient = TableRestProxy::createTableService($connectionString);
```

The following is  the demo code from azure [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-php#create-a-table).

```
<?php 
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Table\TableRestProxy;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\ServiceException;
$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxx;';
$tableClient = TableRestProxy::createTableService($connectionString);
try {
    $tableClient->createTable("mytable");
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
  $code = $e->getCode();
  $error_message = $e->getMessage();
  echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}
```

Comment: I tried using the above method, but I get an error saying: `Error creating resource: [message] fopen(https://eyesav.table.core.windows.net/Tables): failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport &quot;http&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?`

Comment: It means that you need enable https . You could test with connection string DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http. to intsead of https.

Comment: I tried the connection string with http:// but it gives the same error. How do I enable http?

Comment: Please try to  connection string `$connectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=xxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxx;';`

Comment: About how to enable https please refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305954/how-to-enable-https-stream-wrappers)

Comment: This might work for Windows but not Ubuntu, while I am working on Ubuntu.